# Magento2 Integration Token for Mobile Applications

Tags: magento2, rest-api, token, resources

We want to develop mobile applications for Android and iOS which will communicate through Magento2's REST APIs.

What will be the proper way to pass the authorization token to access Magento2's resources?

**What I know:**

For example:
We can use the `V1/guest-carts` endpoint to create a cart on behalf of a guest.

We can create a cart for a logged-in customer and use `/V1/carts/mine` endpoint, calls for a logged-in customer must specify the customer’s token in the header.

Now I want to get the product details by SKU and I will call the `/V1/products/SKU` endpoint, but it will give an error:
[image]

Because a customer or guest does not have access to this resource, I have to provide an Admin Authorization Token or I can create an integration **System > Extensions > Integrations** and provide the **Access Token** to access the resource.

*Resources: Magento_Catalog::products
[image]

**What I don't know:**

Do I have to hardcode the Access Token or Admin User and Password in the mobile application source code?

If yes, customers can use tools like HTTP Toolkit and capture the token from the request and they can just delete a product by calling
`DELETE /V1/products/SKU` endpoint.

If not, what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Services > Magento Web API > Web API Security**. Then select **Yes** from the **Allow Anonymous Guest Access** menu.

The above configuration will only allow GET action on Catalog, CMS, and Store endpoints.

However, it is a possible security concern on production though, and opens you up to bots hitting the site. It is recommended to create a custom ACL.